# FCM 401 "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service"

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm **sometimes** receiving 401's from our firebase project's http v1 endpoint.

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
 "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

These are obviously only happening on ios devices, the problem is, some messages are going through, which means it must be something other than the APNS certificates.

I'm wondering if has something to do with the multiple versions, both prod and dev versions of the app on some devices?

Comment: The same is happening to me, have you found anything to solve this? Some other threads say that you should fill application id and team id on firebase console, but I've done that with no results.